# Is it possible to interrupt a process while backend is still processing?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I would like to ask if it is possible for me to interrupt a process by sending another request to the backend?

For example: I send a request to the server and the backend is processing the request.  While the backend is still busy processing the request, I will interrupt the process by sending another request to the server telling the process to stop.  Is this possible to achieve?

Here is my sample code:

```
`//Ajax code for sending request for starting the process for looping
function showSomething(){
 $(function (){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({something : ''}),
      url: 'veryGoodForSomething.aspx/checkSomething',
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (response){
      //do something
      windows.location.hostname;
      location.reload(true);
      }
   });
 });
}`
```

> The ajax will send the request to start the process to the backend.

```
`//this code will execute for checking
public static bool checkSomething(string something)
{
  bool checking = false;
  while(!checking)
  {
     if(string.isNullOrEmpty(something)){
        checking = furtherChecking(something);
     }
     else
     {
        return checking;
     }
  }
  return checking;
}`
```

Now while the backend is still processing for checking something, I want to interrupt the process by sending another request using an ajax.

```
`//This will interrupt the process by sending 'interrupt' to trigger the
//backend to stop the process while the backend is still running the looping 
//process.
function interruptSomething(){
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({ something : 'interrupt'}),
      url: 'veryGoodForSomething.aspx/checkSomething',
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
         location.reload(true);
      }
    });
  });
}`
```

> By sending the request 'interrupt' while the backend is still running. The process will break.

The real question is that, is this achievable?  Can someone help me with this or can someone provide me a good reference about this?

Comment: When server gets "Cancel" request, server needs to make a note of it somewhere, e.g. referencing it against the username and some sort of "request ID". Backend needs to make a periodic check to see if the task it has been cancelled. If it has, it can throw OperationCancelledException to halt processing.

Comment: I see, hmp... about the referencing thing, can you elaborate that for me?  It seems that I have a very big problem in regards with that.  When the process is still running and call another method from the backend it seems not working at all.

Comment: or much better a sample code that would suffice my needs.  Sorry been new to programming.